# Jira issue status not getting updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jira-rest-api

I am trying to update Jira issue fields through REST Api, I am able to update summary, description, priority, reporter fields but the status.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
string jSonContent = (@"
    {
        ""fields"": {
            ""summary"": ""data"", 
            ""description"": ""modified."",
            ""priority"": {""name"": ""val""}, 
            ""reporter"": {""name"": ""abcdef@gmail.com""},
            ""status"": {""name"": ""WORK IN PROGRESS""}
        }
    }").Replace("data", summ).Replace("modified.", desc).Replace("val", pri);

request.AddParameter("application/json", jSonContent, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the status of an issue the way like that.

To determine what type of fields could be changed with a simple PUT request do a GET for metadata:

```
https://{your-jira-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/editmeta
```

This query in turn will provide you all the fields that you can modify. You won't find status field in the returned JSON object.

Back to your problem: How could be the status of an issue changed? In Jira you have a workflow that holds the possible transition between the states. In order to change the state you need to do a transition. (Exactly the same way as you would do it on UI.)

So first do a GET request like that:

```
https://{your-jira-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

This request will return all possible transitions of your issue's current state. Check which transition you want to perform and note it's ID (in my case the wished ID is 11). With this transition ID you can do a POST request with the JSON payload:

```
https://{your-jira-url}/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions

{
    "transition": {
        "id": "11"
    }
}
```

One additional thing to note: If your transition isn't a simple one then you have to provide more data. I mean a simple transition here where you simply would click on a button on the UI and you wouldn't get an extra screen for the transition. (E.g. you can setup a transition like: you only could resolve an issue if you add a comment to it.) Fortunately, the previously returned transition list contains all the fields that could or that must be provided together with the transition ID.

You can find more information in official Jira [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/).